# Magento applies tax on product prices that already including tax

Tags: magento, cart

I've added products prices with tax included (in the field Price [EUR] [ Including Tax]) 
Now when I put a product in the cart, Magento applies the tax to price that already including the tax!

*Example*: if the product has "Price [EUR] [ Including Tax]"=100€ in the cart I have:

> Product price  € 100
>
> Sub total     € 100
>
> Taxes     € 20
>
> Totale  €120 (but the correct price including taxes is 100€!)

instead I want this:

> Product price  € 100
>
> Sub totale     € 80
>
> Taxes     € 20
>
> Total  €100

I'v tried all the settings and I'm going mad! is there a solution?

Comment: I have this exact same problem on v1.6.1 - which version are you using? Someone recommended re-indexing everything. Didn't work for me but maybe it will for you.

Comment: I'm using ver. 1.7.0.2 and reindex didn't work also for me

Comment: Check out the link below. It says that the shipping origin country (System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings > Origin)  affects the the way the price is displayed in the cart. Strange... http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/78069/   Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

I will repost idophir's comment, that fixed my issue that led me to this question. I wasted hours looking at tax settings and tax rules, to finally find my culprit in shipping origin settings:

> Check out the link below. It says that the shipping origin country
>   (System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings > Origin) affects
>   the the way the price is displayed in the cart. Strange.. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/78069/

Comment: how did you do more than this shipping origin?

Comment: Thanks dude! I wasted hours in the tax settings as well, your solution solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Origin Country is correctly specified under Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings.

Comment: Thanks for this I was busting my head over it. It was misconfiguration there for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System->Configuration->Sales->Taxes->Calculation

and search for Catalog Prices. Set the switch to "yes", then Magento assumes, that the tax is included in the catalog price.

Also check these setting in your store configuration scope, not only in default config.

Comment: That is what I done! Catalog Prices is set on "including taxes" (there is no "yes" option but I think you mean that) but Magento doesnt get it. I've tried also on default theme but nothing. Also checked in the store Views config but there's no Calculation tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i was checking for soutions and came through this topic. Right now i got solution to my problem so telling you here.
In my case i previously selected 'Default Country' as United Kingdom in Default Tax Destination window, and i was signed in from an account with address other than United Kingdom. So all was fine, i tried every option and the tax was not updating on products and shopping cart page. When i logged out and found that it is working ;) Then i relized the issue. So if you have default country for tax calculation, check out the taxes with or without that. Hope it work for you.
And sorry i am late :)

Answer (score -1):

when you go to TAX calculation section (Thats System->Configuration->Sales->Taxes->Calculation) you will find "catalog prices" you can customize whether you want to include price with TAX or not.

Comment: Catalog prices is already on "including taxes" and it doesn't work

Comment: it must work. I have checked this on fresh installation of magento its working buddy.You can check this on fresh new installation of magento.